# php, div nesting issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using a php if statement to display a graphic when users aren't logged in, but the problem is that a.) I'm not great with php yet and b.) the if statement kicks my right sidebar into my `#contentleft` div, when they should be siblings.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

the code:

```
<div id="contentleft">

    <?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            echo 'Welcome, registered user!';

    } else {
            echo '<div id="intro"><p><a href="http://www.wespeakfashion.com/submissions">Sign up</a> and start posting!</p></div>';

    };
    ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <p class="date"><b>Posted on</b> | <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></p>
        <?php global $wpdb;
                $query = "SELECT `ID`, `guid` FROM `$wpdb->posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment' AND `post_parent` = '{$post->ID}'";
                $adimages = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query), OBJECT);
        // To display the first image.. ?>

        <img style="float: center; height: 500px;" src="<?php if(is_public_submission()){echo $adimages[0]->guid;} ?>" />

    <?php the_content(__('Read more'));?><div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="bt-links"><strong>Category:</strong> <?php the_category(', ') ?><br /><?php the_tags('<strong>Tags:</strong> ',' > '); ?></div>

    <!--
    <?php trackback_rdf(); ?>
    -->

    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/r_sidebar.php");?>

</div>
```

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused. You are including the r_sidebar.php inside of your #contentLeft div. Would it not behove you to move it out of the div?

Instead of:

```
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/r_sidebar.php");?>
</div>
```

Do:

```
</div>
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/r_sidebar.php");?>
```

Sorry if that is not the answer (it seems too easy) but if you could elaborate on your problem, I am sure I could be more help!

Comment: Yes, this occurred to me, and I'll probably just go with this solution.  The strange thing, to me, is that `#r_sidebar` is a sibling of `#contentleft` when I'm logged in, but then becomes its child when I'm logged out.  Since I'm writing the PHP myself, I figured it had something to do with my if statements.  Thanks, @andrewpthrop.